# Projects to undertake Using Lasers

Tags: laser, education, applied-physics

I need an economically feasible physics project that would use lasers in any manner preferably with respect to optics for a school projects class XII . Any suggestions are welcome no matter how crazy it sounds !

Comment: Are you asking for 8th grade physics or can it be more advanced?

Comment: as well, each answer must make it clear that lasers can be dangerous

Comment: Well it's for senior high school

Answer (score 2):

There are loads of things you can do with lasers. However, maybe [this one](http://amasci.com/amateur/lasqueal.html) might be of interest?

> It's called "Laser Audio Interferometer" I tried this and it's simple.
>   The mirror reflects the laser beam back down the bore of the HeNe
>   laser tube, forming a second optical cavity external to the laser. Or
>   use a laser pointer instead; I've been told that most will work. A
>   small photovoltaic cell (solar cell or photodiode) collects some of
>   the spill-light from the beam, and the PV cell output is sent to an
>   audio amp and loudspeaker. If you move the wall (or the laser) a tiny
>   bit, then as the "cavity" changes length, it sweeps across hundreds of
>   resonant lengths located every 1/2 wavelength of the light. The light
>   intensity sequentially grows dimmer and brighter, generating a
>   sinewave signal. The frequency is proportional to the velocity of the
>   wall. Connect the PV cell to the microphone input of an audio system,
>   and when the wall is pushed, you hear moans and squeals.

Check out the site above for more ideas

Comment: Very cute. A poor man's interferometer. I shall try this one at home. :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot Dirk Brure !!! But can u educate me a bit about the HeNe laser tube you were talking about in the experiment ??!

Comment: You can just use a cheap laser pointer

Comment: And about the placement of the PV .. It's like very near to the aperture right ?

Comment: Probably. I have not built one myself. Try emailing Bill Beatty who runs the site. Alternatively, you could use a half silvered mirror to split the incoming beam at the aperture

Answer (score 0):

What about a double-slit experiment? If your laser's spatial coherence is long enough, you should be able to place the screen far enough away to get a nice image.
Or go a step further and use a ballpen spring instead of a double slit, and reproduce the diffraction [image of a helix](http://t2ah.blogspot.nl/2013/02/number-25-dna-diffraction-with-spring.html) (similar to what one sees with DNA)!

Comment: Oh I surely will try this one too ... Sounds fun !